# Running a previous GIT version of a Python project in VS Code

Tags: python, git, version-control, git-branch

I'm developing a large GUI project in Python. I use VS Code as my editor and am using git for [local only] version control. I'm using the application as it's continuing to be developed, so I'm looking for a way to modify files but continue to execute earlier versions of the project.

Is there a way to run the version associated with the latest git commit? In this way I can have modules under construction but the application will still run?

Comment: _"execute earlier versions of the project"_ / _"run the version associated with the latest git commit"_ - which do you mean?

Comment: Running the version associated with the latest git commit would be great.

Comment: Is it the case that your current file system has modified some files, but they are not committed yet? And, you wish to run the latest committed version of the files, instead of the version currently in your file system? (If yes to both of those questions, then your question is actually whether or not you can "run" something different than the current state of files, which isn't really a Git question but instead about how you "run" something on your machine.)

Comment: @TTT Precisely correct. In this way I can continue to work on the files but I don't have to keep them in working condition. I can break things but the latest commit will still run so I can keep using the application.

Comment: Or, perhaps this is as simple as switching branches? For example, make a branch for "under construction" work (usually called a feature branch). Commit "in progress" work on that branch (or stash it), and switch back to the good working branch when you wish to run the project.